# longlist selector allows multiple selection of radiobuttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a LongListSelector which has a RadioButton in its DataTemplate(for which the GroupName Property is set).

Now when i select the 1st radiobutton, in parallel 32nd radio button is selected, when i select 2nd parallel 33rd one is selected.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide som code of what you have tried

Comment: you can use value converter

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the virtualisation which is happening in the LongListSelector.

Previously what is tried is, I just bind a list to the itemssource of LLS

So, you need to maintain a property in the viewmodel and bind it to the IsChecked property of radio.